# Defining a Macro having struct argument

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null-pointer

I have a struct named Row :

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t id;
    char username[COLUMN_USERNAME_SIZE];
    char email[COLUMN_EMAIL_SIZE];

} Row;
```

Also, I have defined a Macro :

```
#define size_of_attribute(Struct, Attribute) sizeof(((Struct *)0)->Attribute)

//  size of each attributes
const uint32_t ID_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, id);
const uint32_t USERNAME_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, username);
const uint32_t EMAIL_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, email);
```

Why are we using a null pointer while defining the size_of_attribute Macro to get the size of each data
type in the struct Row? Is there any other way to express the above Macro?

Comment: Because Row is a type name, not a pointer to an instance of a Row.

Comment: There's no way to represent a struct member by itself, it has to be associated with an instance of the struct. If you don't have an existing variable to refer to, you can indirect through a pointer, and a null pointer is one that you can create on the fly like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are we using a null pointer while defining the size_of_attribute Macro to get the size of each data type in the struct Row?

Because:

- You don't have (or need) an instance of `Row`
- In `sizeof expression` the expression is not evaluated. It is in an *"unevaluated context"*. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer causes undefined behavior, but since this expression is not evaluated, the `NULL` pointer is not actually dereferenced and it's therefore safe.

> Is there any other way to express the above Macro?

You could use a similar construct, pretending to actually create a `Struct`:

```c
#define size_of_attribute(Struct, Attribute) (sizeof (Struct){}.Attribute)
```

Again, since the expression after `sizeof` is not evaluated, it doesn't actually create a `Struct`.